# How to checked jquery mobile radio button set via code

Tags: jquery-mobile

I use jquery mobile for build a Phonegap application. I create any radio sets like this :

[image]

I want to checked a radio in a switch case!

```
switch (font_family){ case 'tahoma': $('#radio-1').checked(); ... }
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the picture I am assuming you are using jQM version 1.3.x, however this solution works with 1.4.x too.

Assuming you have markup similar to this:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Font:</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="thefont" id="radio-1" value="arial" checked="checked" />
    <label for="radio-1">Arial</label>
    <input type="radio" name="thefont" id="radio-2" value="verdana" />
    <label for="radio-2">Verdana</label>
    <input type="radio" name="thefont" id="radio-3" value="tahoma" />
    <label for="radio-3">Tahoma</label>
</fieldset>
```

The script to switch to Tahoma would be:

```
$("[name='thefont']").prop( "checked", false ).checkboxradio( "refresh" );
$("#radio-3").prop( "checked", true ).checkboxradio( "refresh" );
```

The first line unchecks all boxes and the second checks the tahoma box. In jQM you must refresh the checkboxradio widget after changing values.

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/senrpo80/)**